# Export to Excel from JTable Java Issue

Tags: java, excel, jtable

I am trying to export jTable output to Excel, 
output file created on path but without my data and I got below Exception
i tried a lots to found any working code with me , but always i got difference issue. please check my code below and give me an answer

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: gnu.xml.dom.DomDocument.getXmlStandalone()Z
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.setDocumentInfo(DOM2TO.java:377)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:131)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:699)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:743)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:357)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.StreamHelper.saveXmlInStream(StreamHelper.java:80)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPartMarshaller.marshallRelationshipPart(ZipPartMarshaller.java:174)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:464)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1441)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:212)
at newtimesheet.ImpMyWork.jButton7ActionPerformed(ImpMyWork.java:1021)
at newtimesheet.ImpMyWork.access$1900(ImpMyWork.java:44)
at newtimesheet.ImpMyWork$17.actionPerformed(ImpMyWork.java:461)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

and I am using Apache POI-3.13 with below code

```
private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        row.createCell(i).setCellValue(model.getColumnName(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            row.createCell(j).setCellValue(
                    model.getValueAt(i, j).toString()
            );
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut;
    try {
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\filename.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImpMyWork.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImpMyWork.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have two issues here

for first issue i found this answer

1- It's some kind of configuration problem caused by having different JARs on your classpath when you compiled your code from those on your classpath when you run it.you can check it in this link

[exception creating xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448336/exception-creating-xml-file)

and i was used some java flowchart library that conflicted with Apache POI-3.13 library so i removed it and it's worked

2- you should replace these code lines

```
  row.createCell(j).setCellValue(
  model.getValueAt(i, j).toString()
```

by

```
   if (model.getValueAt(i, j) != null) {
   val = model.getValueAt(i, j).toString();
   } else {
  val = "NULL"; //you can change value to any thing you want to represent null values
          }
   row.createCell(j).setCellValue(val);
```

to avoid null pointer exception error

that's because if you allow null values in your database you will got null pointer exception