# How to create xml file from java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm building a simple java program that create a XML file.
I'm building this code:

```
public static void creaXMLOrdine(OrdiniNuovo ordine,String codiceNegozio,
            String pathFile){
        try{
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("ORDER");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            Element info = doc.createElement("INFO");
            rootElement.appendChild(info);

            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
            attr.setValue(ordine.getCodiceOrdine()+"");
            info.setAttributeNode(attr);

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            String nomeFile = pathFile+codiceNegozio+"_"+ordine.getCodiceOrdine()+".xml";
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(nomeFile));

            // Output to console for testing
            // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

            transformer.transform(source, result);

            System.out.println("File saved!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.logStackTrace(e);
            VisualMessage.getErrore();
        }
    }
```

But if I try to start this code, I have this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: gnu.xml.dom.DomDocument.getXmlStandalone()Z
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.setDocumentInfo(DOM2TO.java:377)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:131)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:702)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:746)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:359)
>       at supporto.Utility.creaXMLOrdine(Utility.java:142)
>       at PanelFornitoriClienti.PanelNuovoOrdine.inviaOrdineXFile(PanelNuovoOrdine.java:461)
>       at PanelFornitoriClienti.PanelNuovoOrdine$10.actionPerformed(PanelNuovoOrdine.java:776)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exception creating xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448336/exception-creating-xml-file)

Comment: Which line is "Utility.creaXMLOrdine(Utility.java:142) " ?

Comment: English variable names would make the code more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this help:

```
public class UtilsXML {

    private static Document doc;

    // Root "ORDER"
    public static Element addRoot(String rootName) {
        Element root = doc.createElement(rootName);
        doc.appendChild(root);
        return root;
    }

    // Elements inside ROOT like INFO, OTHERS
    public static Element addElement(String rootName, Element root) {
        Element e = doc.createElement(rootName);
        root.appendChild(e);
        return e;
    }

    // Elements inside other elements INFO -> Id, Value
    public static void addNode(Element e, String tagName, String content) {
        Element employ = doc.createElement(tagName);
        employ.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(content));
        e.appendChild(employ);
    }

    // Document
    public static void makeDoc() throws ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docB = dF.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = docB.newDocument();       
    }

    // Save the xml file
    public static void makeFile(String filePath) throws TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory tF = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tF.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        File xml = new File(filePath);
        StreamResult r = new StreamResult(xml);
        t.transform(source, r);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
    try {
        UtilsXML.makeDoc();

        Element order = UtilsXML.addRoot("ORDER");

        Element info = UtilsXML.addElement("INFO", order);
        UtilsXML.addNode(info, "Id", "123456");
        UtilsXML.addNode(info, "Value", "99999");

        Element other = UtilsXML.addElement("OTHERS", order);
        UtilsXML.addNode(other, "Date", "01/01/2017");
        UtilsXML.addNode(other, "Status", "Finish");            

        UtilsXML.makeFile("c:/opensource/myXml.xml");
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
<ORDER>
    <INFO>
        <Id>123456</Id>
        <Value>99999</Value>
    </INFO>
    <OTHERS>
        <Date>01/01/2017</Date>
        <Status>Finish</Status>
    </OTHERS>
</ORDER>
```